# React native react-navigation stack navigator inside bottom tab hide headerShown and bottom tab when in specific stack Screen

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

[image]

I have a stack navigator inside bottom tab I need to hide headerShown and bottom tab when in specific stack Screen.

In this case I have to hide it when I'm only inside `VideoScreen` and `SearchScreen`.

Can you give me a hand?

Link: [expo](https://snack.expo.dev/fMsrxxRX6)

```js
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeScreen({ navigation, type }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{type}</Text>
      {type === 0 && (
        <Button
          style={{ marginTop: 4 }}
          mode="contained"
          buttonColor="#00BFFF"
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate('VideoScreen', {
              patch: 'https://www.google.com/',
            })
          }>
          Video
        </Button>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

function VideoScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  const patch = route?.params?.patch;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Video</Text>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Url: {patch}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function SearchScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>Search</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function HomeStackScreen({ navigation, type }) {
  const patch = navigation?.route?.params?.patch;
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ header: () => null }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home">
        {(props) => <HomeScreen {...props} type={type} />}
      </Stack.Screen>
      <Stack.Screen name="VideoScreen">
        {(props) => <VideoScreen {...props} />}
      </Stack.Screen>
      <Stack.Screen name="SearchScreen">
        {(props) => <SearchScreen {...props} />}
      </Stack.Screen>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarIcon: () => null,
          //headerShown: false
          //header: () => null,
        }}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Tv">
          {(props) => <HomeStackScreen {...props} type={0} />}
        </Tab.Screen>
        <Tab.Screen name="Movie">
          {(props) => <HomeStackScreen {...props} type={1} />}
        </Tab.Screen>
        <Tab.Screen name="Show">
          {(props) => <HomeStackScreen {...props} type={2} />}
        </Tab.Screen>
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 40,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Consider refactoring your navigation structure as discussed here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/